# Specify how many times if statement will be done [bubble sort algorithm]

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
1. for i=1 to n-1 do
2.    for j=1 to n-i do
3.       if a[j]>A[j+1] then
4.          Change A[j] with A[j+1]
```

Tell how many times instruction in 3rd line (the `if` statement) will be done.

I think that this is the first, primary bubble sort algorithm without modifications.

First of all I will consider three cases: the best, average and the worst.


In **the best** way the if statement will be done n-1 times. Data in array will be already segregated. It is enough to walk through the array and end algorithm.


In **the worst** case the if statement will be done:

```html
<a href="http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}" target="_blank"><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}" title="\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tfrac{n(n-1)}{2}" /></a>
```

times. Data in array will not be segregated and each position will be swaped.

In **the average** case the if statement will be done:

```html
<a href="http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tfrac{n(n-1)}{4}" target="_blank"><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tfrac{n(n-1)}{4}" title="\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\tfrac{n(n-1)}{4}" /></a>
```

times? I think that because it wil be the worst case divided by 2.

I want to ask you to check if I think properly. If you think I am wrong please correct me.

Greetings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no checking -  if array is already sorted  - in your code, so the number of if-statements is always

```
Q = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1  = n * (n-1) / 2
```

Not that [Wiki code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) checks

```
   ....    
   until not swapped
```

and may execute `(n-1)` if-statements in the best case (sorted array)

Comment: Do you want me to say that the if statement always will be done: n * (n-1) / 2 no matter of case? Because the array is not always sorted only in the best case

Comment: This code has neither the worst nor the best cases - always the same time. You have to modify it to get a gain for sorted case.

Comment: Right no matter of case the number of if statement comparison will be const.  Number of: Change A[j] with A[j+1] will be different.
It may execute to n-1 because it will be the last comparison. All bubble sort algorithms do the last comparison this is how they know if they can stop. So if array is already sorted answer is n-1 but in any other case it will be always n*(n-1)/2
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The if statement will always be executed the exact same number of times, roughly n^2 / 2.

How often statement 4 will be executed, that's an interesting question. Especially for average number, the mathematics would be interesting.

Comment: I only have to say how many times the if statement will be executed. Your answer is near to MBo answer